# passing an ID of a newly created row within controller

Tags: php, laravel

If I have inserted a new row as follows :

```
$post = new Post();
$post->save();
```

Is there a straight way to call the post_id just created above and insert it in a new row in another table (instead of changing many things to pass it from a view) ?

```
$post = new Post();
$post->save();
$talk = new Talk();
$talk->post_id = // I need to put here the post_id just created. Both inserts 
                //are in the same controller/method
```

Comment: try `$talk->post_id = $post->id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the created post object, since after saved, the post has an unique id:

```php
$post = new Post();
$post->save();
$talk = new Talk();
$talk->post_id = $post->id;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the `$post->id` is not there yet you can try this

```
$post = new Post();
$post->save();
$post = $post->fresh();

$talk = new Talk();
$talk->post_id = $post->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can do this also. Use `Post::latest()->get()->take(1)->pluck('id');` to get the latest added.

Like example below:

```
$post = new Post();
$post->save();
$talk = new Talk();
$talk->post_id = Post::latest()->get()->take(1)->pluck('id');
```

[->latest()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)